# Should users have an "Answers I am proud of" section in their profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile

Since StackExchange profiles are frequently referenced by resumes, CVs, and personal websites, it would be nice if I could pick what answers I have given that I am most proud of. That way recruiters can quickly get an idea of relevant knowledge and skills.

I could then pick answers that are representative or different areas of knowledge that I want to brag about.

So, why not?

Comment: This is exactly what your Careers profile is for, and it allows for this.

Comment: @MichaelPryor - **If** you have one. With it being invite only these days, not everyone can get an invite.

Answer (score 15):

The `About Me` section of the profile is the right place for these.

If you want to add a section about the answers you are most proud of, do that in this section - it is free form markdown/HTML.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to what [Oded mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124388/150235), you can also select your Top Answers from across the network on your [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)  profile, if you have one. Since your Careers profile is structed to be used as a sort of CV, it might be more useful for technical job applications than just your Stack Exchange profile alone.